# Forward http request to other server that will respond to the original requester using java servlets

Tags: java, http, servlets

I have a problem where I have several servers sending HttpRequests (using round robin to decide which server to send to) to several servers that process the requests and return the response.

I would like to have a broker in the middle that examines the request and decides which server to forward it to but the responses can be very big so I would like the response to only be sent to the original requester and not be passed back through the broker. Kind of like a proxy but the way I understand a proxy is that all data is sent back through the proxy. Is this possible?

I'm working with legacy code and would rather not change the way the requests and responses are processed but only put something in the middle that can do some smarter routing of the requests.

All this is currently done using HttpServletRequest/Response and Servlets running on embedded Jetty web servers.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not possible (using HTTP over TCP/IP) because the connection from the source is to the proxy, so the only place the source will listen for a response is there (ie it never made a connection to the target server). But what are you trying to save by doing this? The proxy will hardly add any overhead in terms of CPU, Response times and so on. Since you are using Jetty you can utilise the async processing engine so threads shouldn't be an issue either.

Comment: @stringy05, thank you for the help! The target server may write substantial amounts of data on the PrintWriter of the HttpServletResponse object and I don't want to send the data from target -> proxy -> source. So what I want to save is megabytes sent on the network.

Comment: unfortunately dis-intermediation isn't an option for that, can you make any changes to your servers ie gzip the req/resp or similar?

Comment: Ok, I suspected that it might not be possible. Gzip is a good start and I'm thinking as an alternative I could send back some kind of UUID that the source can use to fetch the data from the target instead. What do you think of that @stringy05?

Comment: That's possible but gets pretty complicated - the target will need to make the response availble, cache it correctly (expire, purge and so on) all of which is fertile ground for defects and things that dont work, so unless the networking is really expensive/cant scale I would avoid it..

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is that the broker component is using the client's IP address when connecting to the target server. That is called [IP spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing).
Are you sure that you want to implement this yourself? Intricacies of network implementation of such a solution are quite daunting. Consider using software that has this option builtin, such as HAProxy. See [these](http://blog.haproxy.com/2013/09/16/howto-transparent-proxying-and-binding-with-haproxy-and-aloha-load-balancer/) [blog](http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/06/05/preserve-source-ip-address-despite-reverse-proxies/) posts.